# Not sure how to debug something like: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Tags: javascript, debugging, error-handling, syntax-error

So I know this is a topic that always gets downvoted no matter what. But I have this page and it used to work fine. I don't know what happened but one day it says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

While this is part of my JS object, and it always worked fine.
I've gone over all my code to see if I didn't forget any brackets or semicolons, but I can find nothing...

Can someone just advice me on how to debug something like this? Cheers!

Here's my JS function until the error. **The error is shown even before the console.log happens which is written above it! How weird is that!**

```````````````````````
fill_grid_json = function(jsonData, result_count){

p_num = parseInt($("#p_num").val());
item_num = parseInt($("#item_num").val());
if(isNaN(item_num)){
    item_num = 20;
}
console.log("m p_num: "+p_num);
console.log("m item_num: "+item_num);

    /*=================＼
    |   Calculate Pages |
    ＼=================*/

calculatePages(result_count,p_num,item_num);

// Calculate item range 
var toItemX = item_num*p_num;
var fromItemX = toItemX-item_num;

if(toItemX>result_count){
    toItemX = result_count;
}
console.log("item range: "+(fromItemX+1)+"-"+toItemX+" / "+result_count);

//Item amount etc.
var hitNum = "<span>"+(fromItemX+1)+"-"+toItemX+"　/　"+result_count+"</span><span class='item_unit'>items</span>";
$(".hit_num").html(hitNum);




var gridItems = []; // Grid Items container array
$.each(jsonData, function(i) {
if(jsonData[i].img_src!=null && jsonData[i].img_src!=""){

    // get JS variables
    var id = jsonData[i].ID;
    var post_title = jsonData[i].post_title;
    var supplier_company = jsonData[i].supplier_company;
    var img_src = jsonData[i].img_src[0];
    var tags = jsonData[i].tags;
    var post_meta = jsonData[i].post_meta;

      //``````````````````````//
     //     MAKE THE GRID ITEM 
    //,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,//

/*******************
    Make the necessary pieces    
********************/

// Add GP Incentive
var post_meta['exw_from_usd'] = GPincentive(post_meta['exw_from_usd']);
var post_meta['exw_to_usd'] = GPincentive(post_meta['exw_to_usd']);
```````````````````````

There at the very end: **post_meta['exw_from_usd']** it bugs. However, this used to never be a problem and always worked... So i'm really confused.

Comment: The error, on any half-decent JavaScript engine, **tells you** where the error is. It has a line number pointing right at it. In any case, the code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll update my question

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I updated the question with the code now! I'm really confused about this. Since it always worked, and just today, I changed nothing but it stopped working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly **have** changed it, because this is invalid code:

```
var post_meta['exw_from_usd'] = GPincentive(post_meta['exw_from_usd']);
```

It's valid without the `var` at the beginning. With the `var` it's invalid and always has been.

I suppose it's possible that you used to visit with a browser whose JavaScript engine ignored the error before, but...

Comment: Why can't I use a var?

Comment: @mesqueeb: Because `var` declares variables, and you're trying to declare an expression (a property accessor expression, `post_meta['exw_from_usd']`), not a variable.

Comment: @mesqueeb Next time, open the page in Chrome and open the developer tools. If you open the file with the error, the syntax error is highlighted in red.

Comment: Thanks! I immidiately found it because of T.J. Crowder, but I had no clue what I did wrong! I'll keep it in mind for the future! See you around Joachim!

Comment: @mesqueeb: Even better, the error is shown in the console. The line and character where the error occurred are listed to the right. That's a clickable link that will open the relevant source file and take you right to the error, highlightd (as Joachim says) in red.